# What strategies are there to document data lineage and keep it updated with a minimum amount of maintenance?

Tags: software-documentation, technical-writing

Quickly communicating [data lineage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_lineage) to other stakeholders in our organization has become increasingly difficult as we scale.

What are effective strategies to address this and keep it maintained?

An example would be customer data that is stored in a data warehouse, processed in various ways, and used for analysis and reporting. The audience would be members of the business intelligence and analytics teams as well as product managers. The data lineage can change as developers add or modify the code.

Comment: What kind of data?

Comment: Could you say more about the problem you're trying to solve?  What kind of data, as Robert already asked, but for what audience(s), over what timespan, and how volatile?

Comment: Customer data that is tracked and processed and stored in various ways from data warehouses to data lakes, data cubes, etc. Audience would be members of business intelligence and analytics teams. The data lineage can change as developers add or modify code. I don't think timespan is relevant here.

Comment: I've update the question with an example.

Comment: Do you want to track the modifications to the code, the changes to the processed output as the code changes, or both?

Comment: The issue is that we are constantly getting questions about where data is coming from and how it got from point A to point B to point Z, as well as what the processing is supposed to do. Without this knowledge, it is very time consuming to troubleshoot problems as well as analyze the data. And then it will be important to have an easily-manageable update process when there are changes.

Comment: I'm still unsure what exactly you want to document. Your latest comment reads more like a request for *distributed tracing* rather than documentation. Do you have a lot of different paths the data can take?

Comment: @Helmar: I've never heard of that but it seems to be in the domain of microservices? We don't follow that architecture. Yes, there are many paths the data can take and things are growing at quite a clip, so it will probably become increasingly complex. I don't think I can make the question clearer, so I will probably self answer in the next week or so when I actually have to make a decision on how we are going to do this.

Comment: It's more common in microservice architectures, yes, but it's basically useful for every distributed system, no matter how small the single components are. Basically it tracks the complete message flow throughout several systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked on a project that sounds similar to yours in which the ability to identify every process that touched every piece of data was vital in order to minimize the amount of code validation that had to be redone whenever any other piece of code changed.

To show the flow of data through processes, we use a three column vertical swim lane diagram where the first column was the input, the middle column the process and the third column was the output.

Of course, the output could be the input to another process, in which case we would draw a flow line looping it back to the first column. These diagrams could potentially get quite long, but the virtue was that you could follow any data back up a easily traced path through all the processes it passed through and identify any data that it was melded with by any process. And because the inputs, processes, and outputs were in separate columns, you could easily identify any input, output, or process you were interested in and trace its role in the system.

Updating it was reasonably simple as well. If you added a new process, you added a new row to the diagram, inserted the process in the middle columns, and then reconnected the data input and output lines. If you added a new data source, you added a new row, inserted the new source, and connected it to the relevant processes.

We also used shading to distinguish between internal and external inputs and processes.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is fairly general, this answer is too.

I'd insert the ETL process itself into the target database. As you have on-site developers this will have to be included in your extraction development. Best add a bit of architecture description and versioning as well to serve the level of understanding of your consumers.

When going after this I'd include a similar step in the actual extraction run process; even a straightforward run-date and field for comments can be worth gold when attempting to generate trends a year hence.